# usb sticks and cards have all become read only

Tags: usb, read-only

For no apparent reason my desktop machine running Ubuntu 12.04 suddenly will not allow me to write to or create files/folders on any usb drive (memory sticks and cards). All work perfectly in my laptop running exactly the same system. I've checked all the usual ideas - it is not locked, I have formatted it on both machines and only the one machine has the problem.

I'm not an experienced user so keep it as simple as possible please!

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes the USB format is a Windows type FAT or NTFS

The system may have lost or not have the files for writing to NTFS partitions installed.

I recommend to try this in terminal: `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` and install both ntfs-3g and all its dependencies.

Now, reboot your system, and attempt to open the NTFS drive for write access. You should now be able to write to the NTFS drive.